# AMP + Яндекс Турбо?

Tags: amp

подскажите как работает в связке Яндекс Турбо + AMP
Насколько мне сказали можно использовать один из двух. И тогда снова проблема что если к примеру я использую яндекс турбо то сайт храниться на серверах яндекса и показатели в гугле падают. Правильно ли это или нет? И можно использовать их обеих?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно скопировать в настройках плагина адрес rss-фида для турбо  и вставить в раздел Турбо-страницы -> Источники в Вебмастере. Там же есть и другие настройки.
[Тут](https://youtu.be/BfE2zcbysrM) небольшая видео-инструкция на эту тему